# No `predict_dataloader()` method defined to run `Trainer.predict`

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader, lightening

I am trying to get predictions from my model based on the test set dataloader (will want to save both x and y^hat, which I need to test later on).

I tried:

```
my_results = trainer.predict(model = model, datamodule=dm)
```

With the following items present in my code:

```
class TimeseriesDataset(Dataset):   
    '''
    Custom Dataset subclass. 
    Serves as input to DataLoader to transform X 
      into sequence data using rolling window. 
    DataLoader using this dataset will output batches 
      of `(batch_size, seq_len, n_features)` shape.
    Suitable as an input to RNNs. 
    '''
    def __init__(self, X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, seq_len: int = 1):
        self.X = torch.tensor(X).float()
        self.y = torch.tensor(y).float()
        self.seq_len = seq_len

    def __len__(self):
        return self.X.__len__() - (self.seq_len-1)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return (self.X[index:index+self.seq_len], self.y[index+self.seq_len-1])


class LSTMRegressor(pl.LightningModule):
    '''
    Standard PyTorch Lightning module:
    https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lightning_module.html
    '''
    def __init__(self, 
                 n_features, 
                 hidden_size, 
                 seq_len, 
                 batch_size,
                 num_layers, 
                 dropout, 
                 learning_rate,
                 criterion):
        super(LSTMRegressor, self).__init__()
        self.n_features = n_features
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.criterion = criterion
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=n_features, 
                            hidden_size=hidden_size,
                            num_layers=num_layers, 
                            dropout=dropout, 
                            batch_first=True)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 2)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # lstm_out = (batch_size, seq_len, hidden_size)
        lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(x)
        y_pred = self.linear(lstm_out[:,-1])
        return y_pred
    
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        loss = self.criterion(y_hat, y)
        # result = pl.TrainResult(loss)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return loss
    
def predict_step(self, batch, batch_idx): 
    with torch.no_grad():
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        return x, y_hat
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        loss = self.criterion(y_hat, y)
        # result = pl.EvalResult(checkpoint_on=loss)
        self.log('val_loss', loss)
        enable_checkpointing = True, #ModelCheckpoint(monitor='val_loss')
        # checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
        # monitor='val_loss',
        # dirpath='./lstm',
        # filename='lstm{epoch:02d}-val_loss{val/loss:.2f}',
        # auto_insert_metric_name=False
    # )
        return loss
    
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self(x)
        loss = self.criterion(y_hat, y)
        # result = pl.EvalResult()
        self.log('test_loss', loss)
        enable_checkpointing = True, #ModelCheckpoint(monitor='test_loss')   #TODO check if loss is the thing to return in this function
        return loss
```

and:

```
class CryptoDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    '''
    PyTorch Lighting DataModule subclass:
    https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datamodules.html

    Serves the purpose of aggregating all data loading 
      and processing work in one place.
    '''
    
    def __init__(self, seq_len = 1, batch_size = 128, num_workers=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.num_workers = num_workers
        self.X_train = None
        self.y_train = None
        self.X_val = None
        self.y_val = None
        self.X_test = None
        self.X_test = None
        self.columns = None
        self.preprocessing = None


def setup(self, stage=None):
    '''
    Data is resampled to hourly intervals.
    Both 'np.nan' and '?' are converted to 'np.nan'
    'Date' and 'Time' columns are merged into 'dt' index
    '''

    if stage == 'fit' and self.X_train is not None:
        return 
    if stage == 'test' or stage == 'predict' and self.X_test is not None:
        return
    if stage is None and self.X_train is not None and self.X_test is not None:  
        return
    
    path = './eth_data_1d.csv'
    
    df = pd.read_csv(
        path, 
        sep=',', 
        infer_datetime_format=True, 
        low_memory=False, 
        na_values=['nan','?'], 
        index_col='Time'
    )
    
    y = pd.concat([df['Top'], df['Btm']], axis=1, keys=['Top', 'Btm'])

    X = df.dropna().copy()        
    self.columns = X.columns

    X_cv, X_test, y_cv, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False
    )

    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(
        X_cv, y_cv, test_size=0.25, shuffle=False
    )

    preprocessing = StandardScaler()
    preprocessing.fit(X_train)

    self.X_train = preprocessing.transform(X_train)
    self.y_train = y_train.values.reshape((-1, 2))
    self.X_val = preprocessing.transform(X_val)
    self.y_val = y_val.values.reshape((-1, 2))
    self.X_test = preprocessing.transform(X_test)
    self.y_test = y_test.values.reshape((-1, 2))
    
def train_dataloader(self):
        train_dataset = TimeseriesDataset(self.X_train, 
                                          self.y_train, 
                                          seq_len=self.seq_len)
        train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, 
                                  batch_size = self.batch_size, 
                                  shuffle = False, 
                                  num_workers = self.num_workers)
        
        return train_loader

    def val_dataloader(self):
        val_dataset = TimeseriesDataset(self.X_val, 
                                        self.y_val, 
                                        seq_len=self.seq_len)
        val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, 
                                batch_size = self.batch_size, 
                                shuffle = False, 
                                num_workers = self.num_workers)

        return val_loader

    def test_dataloader(self):
        test_dataset = TimeseriesDataset(self.X_test, 
                                         self.y_test, 
                                         seq_len=self.seq_len)
        test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, 
                                 batch_size = self.batch_size, 
                                 shuffle = False, 
                                 num_workers = self.num_workers)

        return test_loader
```

Gives me the following error:

```
MisconfigurationException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/xxx/ai_bt/model.ipynb Cell 22 in <cell line: 34>()
      1 # train on test set too! : see below
      2 # trainer.test(dataloaders=test_dataloaders)
      3 
   (...)
     30 # with torch.no_grad():
     31     # predictions = trainer.predict(model, dm)
---> 34 my_results = trainer.predict(model = model, datamodule=dm)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py:1025, in Trainer.predict(self, model, dataloaders, datamodule, return_predictions, ckpt_path)
   1000 r"""
   1001 Run inference on your data.
   1002 This will call the model forward function to compute predictions. Useful to perform distributed
   (...)
   1022     Returns a list of dictionaries, one for each provided dataloader containing their respective predictions.
   1023 """
   1024 self.strategy.model = model or self.lightning_module
-> 1025 return self._call_and_handle_interrupt(
   1026     self._predict_impl, model, dataloaders, datamodule, return_predictions, ckpt_path
   1027 )

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py:723, in Trainer._call_and_handle_interrupt(self, trainer_fn, *args, **kwargs)
    721         return self.strategy.launcher.launch(trainer_fn, *args, trainer=self, **kwargs)
...
--> 197     raise MisconfigurationException(f"No `{loader_name}()` method defined to run `Trainer.{trainer_method}`.")
    199 # predict_step is not required to be overridden
    200 if stage == "predict":

MisconfigurationException: No `predict_dataloader()` method defined to run `Trainer.predict`.
```

It must be something silly because I can't figure out what the dataloader refers to. the dm argument works fine during training...

**Update: based on @Mikel B's answer I added:**

```
def predict_dataloader(self):
        predict_dataset = TimeseriesDataset(self.X_test, 
                                         self.y_test, 
                                         seq_len=self.seq_len)
        predict_loader = DataLoader(predict_dataset, 
                                 batch_size = self.batch_size, 
                                 shuffle = False, 
                                 num_workers = self.num_workers)

        return predict_loader
```

Which results in:

```
---> 44     output = model(batch)
     45     output = model.proba(output) # if not part of forward already
     46     prediction_list.append(output)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1130, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1126 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1127 # this function, and just call forward.
   1128 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/Users/user/ai_bt/model.ipynb Cell 22 in LSTMRegressor.forward(self, x)
     32 def forward(self, x):
     33     # lstm_out = (batch_size, seq_len, hidden_size)
---> 34     lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(x)
     35     y_pred = self.linear(lstm_out[:,-1])
     36     return y_pred
...
--> 731     is_batched = input.dim() == 3
    732     batch_dim = 0 if self.batch_first else 1
    733     if not is_batched:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dim'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined `predict_dataloader()` in you `LightningDataModule`:

```py
class MNISTDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, data_dir: str = "path/to/dir", batch_size: int = 32):
        super().__init__()
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def setup(self, stage: Optional[str] = None):
        self.mnist_test = MNIST(self.data_dir, train=False)
        self.mnist_predict = MNIST(self.data_dir, train=False)
        mnist_full = MNIST(self.data_dir, train=True)
        self.mnist_train, self.mnist_val = random_split(mnist_full, [55000, 5000])

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.mnist_train, batch_size=self.batch_size)

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.mnist_val, batch_size=self.batch_size)

    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.mnist_test, batch_size=self.batch_size)

    # THIS IS WHAT YOU ARE MISSING
    def predict_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.mnist_predict, batch_size=self.batch_size)

    def teardown(self, stage: Optional[str] = None):
        # Used to clean-up when the run is finished
        ...
```

Without this method the `trainer` does not know which data to load for the `predict_step`

Comment: Oh course! Adding this, I do get an error still: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dim'. 

Which is strange because the exact same dataloader works fine during training. I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: What do you get if you print the type of the predict instance that is going into the model? It needs to be a tensor, seems that you are inputing a list. What if you transform it into a tensor in that case?

Comment: Overwriting the def predict_step() helped in the end. Not sure why I had to do that. But now I nicely get to return both x and y_hat. Only thing is that the x is broken up per LSTM sequence length and hence has many repeated values. Any way to easily reshape this?